# Web server database connection monitoring

Tags: monitoring, asp.net, windows

Windows server 2003/2008 + ASP.NET website

Typical web server monitoring system is capable of monitoring the availability of web page, latency. What I am looking for is something that can monitoring the connection between web server and database. Once the DB instance goes down, send notification email. Can the community give me some suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need explicit database monitoring you need to install a probe on your server (nagios etc)

But: You can create a super-simple asp.net page that connects to your db. If this connection fails the page will not load => it can be monitored with *any* website monitoring system.

Same approach is shown here (just with diskspace instead of db connection):

http://blog.alertfox.com/2011/01/monitoring-disk-space-and-other-status.html